# Apache server localhost working but not server IP

Tags: php, apache, apache2, httpd.conf, htdocs

I made a Apache server on windows server 2008. Localhost is working but when i type the server ip it doesn't connect to the Apache server. What whould be the proper solution?

Comment: have you whitelabeled the ports?

Comment: How to whitelable the ports? My port is :78 and :5533

Answer (score 0):

You may configure your firewall  to allow port 80 and also, configure the tomcat server to allow port 80 on http connections.